# QuantLib not importing appropriate engine for solving differential equations

Tags: python-3.x, quantlib

How do I get around the traceback error: module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'BaroneAdesiWhaleyEngine'?

Do I need to manually install QuantLib and specifically this Engine? How do I do that?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.20 ([release notes](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/releases/tag/QuantLib-SWIG-v1.20)) the class was exported to Python as `BaroneAdesiWhaleyApproximationEngine`, which was its name in C++ all along.  The old name was kept available for a while, but in version 1.24 ([release notes](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/releases/tag/QuantLib-SWIG-v1.24)) it was removed.  You'll have to use the new name now.